# Android RTSP streaming over TCP

Tags: android, tcp, android-mediaplayer, vlc, rtsp

We are facing some issue regarding TCP streaming, So we need help.

Project requirement:
RTSP streaming over TCP.
Take snapshot of streaming video.
Streaming multiple videos in single screen.

We have used Android media player to stream RTSP. But media player supports RTSP only over UDP protocol, It fails over TCP. We need to support RTSP streaming over TCP protocol in the project.

Android VLC player supports streaming RTSP over TCP protocol. We have tried VLC using this link  https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/. But we cannot play multiple videos in single screen, also snapshot feature cannot be implemented since VLC uses SurfaceView to load the video.

Any suggestion regarding "streaming multiple RTSP videos over TCP" and "Snapshot" would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

now the VLC code is updated.

- it supports multiple instance.
- You can use texture view to get a snapshot gather than surface view.

hope this helps ;)